# Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R, f(x) =-x$. If the domain and codomain are equipped with the half-open interval topology determine if $f$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R, f(x) =-x$. If the domain and codomain are equipped with the half-open interval topology determine if $f$ is continuous.

So the topology is generated by intervals of the form $[a,b), a,b \in \Bbb R$. Now to show that $f$ is continuous I have to satisfy that for every open $V \subset \Bbb R$ I have that $f^{-1}(V) $ is open in $\Bbb R$?

Take $V \subset \Bbb R$, now $V$ is of the form $[a,b)$ and the preimage is of the form $$f^{-1}(V) = \{x \in \Bbb R \mid f(x) \in V\} = \{x \in \Bbb R \mid -x \in [a,b)\}$$

How can I proceed in showing that this is open? It seems that the map $f$ maps intervals of the form $[a,b)$ to intervals of the form $(-b,-a]$?

Comment: It's not open. Think about it this way: can you find a basic neighbourhood of $-a$ contained in $(-b, -a]$?

Comment: Isn't that called the upper limit topology? And by definition open?

Comment: If the topology on the codomain is generated by intervals of the form $[c, d)$ as your question indicates, then you would need to find some $[c, d)$ contained in $(-b, -a]$ that contains $-a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f^{-1}[0,1)=(-1,0]$. If this is open then  we can write $(-1,0]=\bigcup_i [a_i,b_i)$. Now $0$ belongs to LHS so it must belong to $[a_i,b_i)$ for some $i$. But then there exists $y >0$ such that $y$ belongs to RHS. This is a  contradiction since $y$ does not belong to LHS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since the topology on the codomain is the same as in the domain shouldn't $f^{-1}[0,1) = [-1,0)$ instead of $f^{-1}[0,1) = (-1,0]$?

Comment: @Filippo Calculation of $f^{-1}[0,1)$ has nothing to do with the topology. $0 \leq x <1$ iff $-1 <-x \leq 0$.